# Excel - Delete all rows based on condition in one column, in one cell

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, row

I have two columns. I want to delete all the rows that are based on a certain condition in one of the columns.

For example -

```
Name    Condition
Andrew  Yes
Andrew  Yes
Andrew  Yes
Andrew  No
```

So for the above I want to delete all the rows because, one of rows has a No in it. Hence all 4 rows should be deleted because in the condition column one of the cells has a "No" in it.

I have tried using a pivot table but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: For delete operation, you need VBA coding. Or filter data based on your desired condition then select visible cells and then delete entire row.

Comment: In addition to what Harum24hr wrote: You could show more of your sample data. Because you only showed what should get removed, not what should remain.